# Rewriting a fprint function in golang

Tags: go, variadic-functions

I've found a package for printing colours in golang. However, it has no simple way of printing *no* colour. And as my code was becoming messier due being filled with print statements I wanted to rewrite it. However, I have no clue how to create fstrings in a function.

How it looks in my code:

```
color.HEX("#B0DFE5").Print("[" + time.Now().Format("15:04:05") +"] ")
color.HEX("#FFFFFF").Printf("Changed %s to %s\n", name, new_name)
```

What I've created for normal prints:

```
func cprintInfo(message string) {
    color.HEX("#B0DFE5").Print("[!] ")
    color.HEX("#FFFFFF").Printf(message + "\n")   
}
```

What I'm looking to create:

```
cfprintInfo("Hello %s", world)
// Hello world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Printf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/gookit/color.v1#RGBColor.Printf) expects a format string and (optional) arguments:

```
func (c RGBColor) Printf(format string, a ...interface{})
```

So mimic that:

```
func cfprintInfo(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    color.HEX("#B0DFE5").Print("[!] ")
    color.HEX("#FFFFFF").Printf(format, args...)
}
```